# How do I use HMR when developing react-native on a device?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I can launch **Hot Module Replacement** on the simulator, because I can directly type on the keyboard.

However I do not know how to access these debug options (`cmd+ctrl+z` or equivalent in windows) on the actual device.

Else if not using HMR, do you rebuild from **Xcode**? Any other method to reload the app rather than that? It can be slow.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just "shake" the device to open the debug menu :)

Comment: Thanks! But that made me make another question, more disturbing. Really do I have to shake a huge iPad? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839666/how-do-i-open-react-natives-dev-menu-on-real-device

Answer (score 1):

Just do `cmd+d` on mac click `Debug JS Remotely` after you need to launch `Enable Hot Reloading` just one time.

Take a look to [Exponent](https://exponentjs.com/)

Comment: Thanks, but remember I can't `cmd+d` on the tablet! So I still have to shake it. Exponent however is a great advise!