# how to connect app to development server and makes it sensitive to changes?

Tags: react-native

I'm working on an app that was developed by someone else and referred to me for debugging. I downloaded the project from git and now when I install it on my android device using the react-native run-android command and change the codes and save it, nothing happens in the app and I have to reinstall using "react-native run-android" to see the changes. what should I do to see the changes online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was quite simple. The only thing I had to do was to shake the device and click on "enable hot reloading" in the opened menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the Gradle and run again. and also check are you able to get developer menu by clicking ctrl/command + m.

Comment: I cannot access the developer menu

Comment: Can you please try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839666/how-do-i-open-react-natives-dev-menu-on-real-device?

Comment: I have already tried the solutions that are mentioned in the link and the problem still exists.